# Delete specific folder/files in all the directories of the server from the Ansible Playbook

Tags: linux, ansible, devops, ansible-facts

I want to remove the all "test" folders inside the subdirectories of server. Like below is the path of "test" folders. There are multiple directories in home folder, So, I cant specify all the paths in playbook.

Path: `/home/*/test`

I have write the below playbook for this but it doesnt work.

```
tasks:
   - name: Delete the folder
     file:
       path: "{{ item }}"
       state: absent
     with_items:
       - "/home/*/test"
```

Could you please let me know the solution for it..

I have tried to use file_glob but doesn't work. I want to delete the test folders from all the subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

Use the module [*find*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#ansible-builtin-find-module-return-a-list-of-files-based-on-specific-criteria). For example, given the tree

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/home/
/tmp/home/
├── a
├── b
│   └── test
└── c
    └── test
```

Declare the list of the paths

```yaml
  test_dirs: "{{ out.files|map(attribute='path') }}"
```

Then, the task

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: /tmp/home
        file_type: directory
        patterns: test
        recurse: true
      register: out
```

gives

```yaml
  test_dirs:
  - /tmp/home/c/test
  - /tmp/home/b/test
```

Use the list to delete the directories

```yaml
    - file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        state: absent
      loop: "{{ test_dirs }}"
```

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/home/
/tmp/home/
├── a
├── b
└── c
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    test_dirs: "{{ out.files|map(attribute='path') }}"

  tasks:

    - find:
        paths: /tmp/home
        file_type: directory
        patterns: test
        recurse: true
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: test_dirs

    - file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        state: absent
      loop: "{{ test_dirs }}"
```